# Plot vertical lines for differentiate different "class" of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe loos something like this

```
Year<-c(2009, 2008.75, 2008.5, 2008.25, 2008, 2007.66, 2007.33, 2007, 2006, 2006.75, 2006.5, 2006.25, 2005, 2005.66, 2005.33, 2004)
Depth<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
Data<-runif(16, -1.0, 1.0)
dd<-data.frame(Year, Depth, Data)
```

Now... I need to plot Data vs Depth, and so far I'm using ggplot2 with a code that looks something like this

```
G<-ggplot(dd, aes(Depth, Data))+
    geom_line(color="blue3", size=.25)
G<-G+ggtitle("Title")+theme_bw()
G<-G+labs(x="Depth (m)",  y=expression("norm value"))
G
```

But I need also to add vertical lines that differentiate different "sections" of the graph corresponding for the start of each year (i.e. each integer of the Year column of the dd dataset). I don't need it to be fancy, I just need thin, black, vertical lines at each corresponding depth for the integer value of the Year. Is it possible with ggplot2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `geom_vline` like this:

```
G + geom_vline(xintercept = dd$Depth[dd$Year %% 1 == 0])
```

It could alternately be written like this:

```
library(dplyr)
G + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Depth), data = ~ filter(.x, Year %% 1 == 0))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Very nifty solution. Although I find the OP's idea of visualisation a bit unfortunate... (e.g., the early years are on the right side, "depth" instead of year as x variable...)